# CruiseControl.Net Dependent Projects configuration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I want to set up the following CI configurations for the same .net project:

1. Build and run unit tests (CCNet Project1).
2. Build and run acceptance (end-to-end integration) tests (CCNet Project2).

So, I need somehow to configure that Project2 should be executed only in case Project1 succeeds and to use the same revision as for the last successfull Project1 revision.

I managed to configure Remote Project trigger. However, it is not unclear for me how to use the same revision number when getting sources from SVN as for the last successfull Project1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two CCNET projects are tightly coupled my advice would be to let Project1 get the sources from SVN and keep the build version numbers synchronized.

You need to configure the trigger and the labeller for the dependent project. You use [Project Trigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Trigger) as trigger (I assume that is what you meant by "Remote Project trigger") and [Remote Project Labeller](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Remote_Project_Labeller) as labeller:

```
<project>
  <name>Project2</name>
  <sourcecontrol type="nullSourceControl" />
  <triggers>
    <projectTrigger>
      <project>Project1</project>
    </projectTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <labeller type="remoteProjectLabeller">
    <project>Project1</project>
  </labeller>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```